# Repetitive Data in JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist

I want to repeat the `unit` and `pcs` sections in the JSON file.

For example:

```
$rows[] = array(
    'unit' => 'Example',
    'pcs' =>
        array('1 for Example', '2 for Example'),
);
```

Result:

```
[
 {"unit":"Example","pcs":["1 for Example","2 for Example"]}
]
```

How to do this type of [JSON](http://www.json.org/)?

Target:

```
[
 {"unit":"Example",
  "pcs":
      ["1 for Example","2 for Example"]},
 {"unit":"ExampleSecond",
  "pcs":
      ["1 for ExampleSecond","2 for ExampleSecond"]}
]
```

Comment: Could you please spend a minute and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: Just create a (nested) PHP array and call json_encode on it. Numeric arrays translate into JSON lists ([]), associative arrays and PHP objects translate into objects ({}). Example:

```
$a = array(
    array('foo' => 'bar'),
    array('foo' => 'baz'));
$json = json_encode($a);
```

Gives you:

```
[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the JSON format I've targeted is not the way you specify. Bu arada websiteniz oldukca zengin içeriğe sahip sanırım.

Comment: I've made a little change on your code diagram and I've captured the format I've been targeting. Thank you man! Teşekkürler Konya'ya selam :)